# Animating a solar system: 'child of' constraint resets after 180° rotation when influence is lower than 1

Tags: animation, constraints

So I'm trying to animate a solar system with planets progressively being less and less influenced by the sun's rotation as they stand further and further away.
I set an empty object where the sun is, attached all the planets to the controller with a Child of constraints and a Pivot constraint linked to the controller as well, and tweaked the influences; for instance, the closest planet has a influence of 1, the furthest 0.2.

Since I want the planets to do a full circle, I need the sun to rotate something like 3600°. Unfortunately, every time it passes 180°, every object snaps back to its original location (except for the one with its influence set to 1).

Is there something I'm not doing right or is that a limitation of Blender? is there a way around it? (I don't know anything about animating in Blender).
The version in 3.1.
Thank you!

Comment: pls upload a simplified version of your solar system in which the problem still persist, so we can check it out. thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you should use drivers for that.

1. create empty in center and parent a planet to it:

[image]

2. Duplicate to add more planets

[image]

3. Add control empty:

[image]

4. Press RMB on Z rotation of control empty and select "Copy as new driver"
5. Paste drivers in the empties of the planet's in Z rotation (RMB ⇾ Paste driver), values will become pink:

[image]

6. In context menu, select Edit driver. Set type to scripted expression, and in expression set `rotation_euler*0.3` (multiply by your coefficient).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I ended up going that route, indeed, following a clock animation tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vRif78aoHf0

Comment: Just to elaborate on why you can't use the Child Of constraint as you planned: constraints' factors are to be considered as a ratio between your object's state with and without the constraint. When you set a frame to be 50%, it's not "50% from the previous frame", it's actually "50% from no constraint on the same frame".